# Finding a coordinate vector given an ortho-normal basis

Tags: linear-algebra, change-of-basis

How would I do this problem? (these are all column vectors)

Find the coordinate vector $[\mathbf{v}]_b$ is $\mathbf{v}=\left[3, 5, -4\right]$ and $B$ is the orthonormal basis $$B=\{[\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}},0,\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}],[-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}},0,\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}],[[0,-1,0]\}$$

I tried to take the first component of v and multiplied it by the first component of B, and did the same for the others, but that did not seem to work.

Comment: Take the dot product of $v$ with each basis element.

Comment: How do you mean 'that did not seem to work'? It's going to be $[-\frac1{\sqrt2},\, -\frac7{\sqrt2},\, - 5]$.

Comment: math error, my bad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should find the triple $(l_1,l_2,l_3)$ s.t $v=l_1 [\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}},0,\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}]+l_2 [-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}},0,\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}]+l_3 [[0,-1,0]$. In other words, you have to solve the following 3x3 system.

$\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} l_1-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}l_2+0\cdot l_3=3$

$0\cdot l_1+0\cdot l_2-1\cdot l_3=5$

$\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}l_1+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}l_2+0\cdot l_3=-4$

So the requested vector is $[l_1,l_2,l_3]$.